# Como ocultar a mensagem em bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Observem a imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu abro o formulário modal ele já aparece a faixa de mensagem de validação, eu gostaria que ele somente aparecesse quando a validação fosse ativada.

É esse trecho de código;

```
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="false"></span>
                          <span id="erroMsgUJ"></span>
                          <span id="erroMsgPeriodoInicio"></span>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Coloca o código javascript que faz a validação e mostra o alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só vc já começar ele com `display:none`, para isso vc pode usar a classe nativa `.hidden` do Bootstrap 3 como vc pode consultar aqui: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes-show-hide

```
// Classes
.show {
  display: block !important;
}
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Então sua `div` de *alert* ficaria inicialmente assim, depois vc retira o `.hidden` e coloca o `.show` pelo JS já usando essas classes nativas do BS3

```
<div class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert">
```

Comment: não funcionou, mas eu vi a documentação, eu acho que deve está faltando alguma coisa!

Comment: por favor, baseado no meu código como ele iria ficar?

Comment: @wladyband apenas sso deveria resolver `<div class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert">` mas se não resolveu, é porque vc tem algum Script que esta colocando `display:block` nesse elemento... talvez algum jQuery que está dando show() no elemento... só inspecionando para saber pq a tag pode estar assim  `<div class="alert alert-danger hidden" role="alert" style="display:block">`  ai não tem como funcionar, vc teria que tirar esse block pelo JS tb